# Matrix derivative/ Apply derivative on matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Assume you have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ where every element is a function of $t$. Also assume you have the row vector of constants $b$ with the size $1\times n$. Now, I am trying to find the $\frac{d(bA^{-1}b^T)}{dt}$. I found some relations in the book "The Matrix Cookbook" (pages 9 and 10) like $\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=-A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}$ and $\frac{d(bA^{-1}b^T)}{dA}=-A^{-T}bb^TA^{-T}$ but I don't know how to continue from there. Is it possible to say $\frac{d(bA^{-1}b^T)}{dt}=\frac{d(bA^{-1}b^T)}{dA}\frac{dA}{dt}$? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= bA^{-1}b^T, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,M = \frac{dA}{dt} \cr
}$$
Then use the 2nd formula from the cookbook to write the differential of the function as
$$\eqalign{
 df &= -A^{-T}b^TbA^{-T}:dA \cr
}$$(where the colon represents the inner/Frobenius product)

Now substitute the time derivative of $A$
$$\eqalign{
df &= -A^{-T}b^TbA^{-T}:M\,dt \cr\cr
\frac{df}{dt} &= -A^{-T}b^TbA^{-T}:M \cr
  &= -{\rm tr}\big(A^{-1}b^TbA^{-1}M\big) \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:** $\,\,$The cookbook formula was derived for column vectors, so it had to be modified to account for your preference for row vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very helpful explanation.